# PHP foreach with cURL and Multiple Array Merge to Multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to send a cURL request within a foreach loop and then take the multiple arrays returned and place them in one array to be accessed outside of the loop. Here is what I have:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3');

foreach ($array as $go){

//the cURl request occurs and returns the below variable. 

$json_result_dcam = json_decode($result_dcam);
$json_result_dcam_array = (array) $json_result_dcam;
echo "<pre>"; print_r($json_result_dcam_array);

}
```

The print returns:

```
Array
(
[code] => 200
[response] => Success
[found] => 
[status] => 
)

Array
(
[code] => 200
[response] => Success
[found] => 
[status] => 
)

Array
(
[code] => 200
[response] => Success
[found] => 1
[status] => Approved: Not Printed
 )
```

What I need to do is merge these arrays to one multidimensional array that I can access outside of the loop.

Comment: Create the wrapper array outside of the loop, `$wrapper = [];`, then insert new items into the array within the loop, `$wrapper[] = json_result_dcam_array;`, then you can see your final array at the end outside of the loop, `print_r($wrapper);`.

Comment: If you're working with associative arrays, you can pass `true` into `json_decode`, `$json_result_dcam = json_decode($result_dcam, true);` instead of casting.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form, without any further processing of the responses would be like:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3');
$result = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $go){

//the cURl request occurs and returns the below variable. 

$json_result_dcam = json_decode($result_dcam);
$json_result_dcam_array = (array) $json_result_dcam;
   foreach ($json_result_dcam_array as $header){
       $result[$i] = $header;
       $i++;
   }


}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Comment: this returns in one flat array -- i need each array to be turned to a multidimensional array. Here is what it is returning: 'Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => Success
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 200
    [5] => Success
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 200
    [9] => Success
    [10] => 1
    [11] => Approved: Not Printed
    [12] => 200
    [13] => Success
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 200
    [17] => Success
    [18] => 
    [19] => 
    [20] => 200
    [21] => Success
    [22] => 1
    [23] => Approved: Not Printed
)'

Comment: I've updated the answer, please see if that's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add all results to an array which you can then later iterate i.e.:

```
$json_result_dcam = [];
$array = array('1', '2', '3');

foreach ($array as $go){
    //the cURl request occurs and returns the below variable. 

    $json_result_dcam[] = json_decode($result_dcam, true);
}

var_dump($json_result_dcam);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have arrays in an array

**option 1**
declare them as an array of arrays

```
$myAoA = array( array(), array(), array() );
```

**option 2**

use the `array_pop` method to add items to the end of an array

```
$myAoA = [];
array_push($myAoA, $myArr1);
array_push($myAoA, $myArr2);
array_push($myAoA, $myArr3);
```

which would put them in order like this

```
[ $myArr1, $myArr2, $myArr3 ]
```

**option 3**

use `array_unshift` method to add items to the beginning of an array

```
$myAoA = [];
array_unshift($myAoA, $myArr1);
array_unshift($myAoA, $myArr2);
array_unshift($myAoA, $myArr3);
```

which would put them in order like this

```
[ $myArr3, $myArr2, $myArr1 ]
```